# Android com.android.camera.action.CROP fix smallest dimension

Tags: android, image, android-intent, photo, crop

I need to crop image, to square. I use that function:

```
private void crop(Uri imageUri) {
    File photoGallery = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp_image.jpg");
    checkImageSize(photoGallery);
    Intent cropIntentGallery = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntentGallery.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
    cropIntentGallery.putExtra("crop", true);
    cropIntentGallery.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntentGallery.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntentGallery.putExtra("outputX", PHOTO_SIZE);
    cropIntentGallery.putExtra("outputY", PHOTO_SIZE);
    cropIntentGallery.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoGallery));
    startActivityForResult(cropIntentGallery, REQ_EDIT_CAMERA);
}
```

And it opens crop activity, but I can change X and Y size. 
What I need is to fix smallest dimension, so if image was made in landscape mode - user will be able to cut left or/and right edges, if in portrait - top or/and bottom edges.
Is there are some extra parameter to do this?

BTW, where I can find list of all possible intent extras? (like: "aspectX", "outputX"...)

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Ok, but still I will use it.

Comment: What about list of all possible extras?

Comment: There are an infinite number of possible extras. You are welcome to iterate over all million-plus Android apps and force each developer, at gunpoint, to document whether they support this `Intent` action and, if they do, what extras they support. And, you will need to do this continuously, since apps get changed all the time. This will be time-consuming, illegal in many jurisdictions, and hazardous to your health. Or, you could use a cropping library, as pointed out in my blog post.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that libraries and later will write here my results.